# How to make an realistic jump in spritekit

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, game-physics

I want the jump to be realistic and the sprite not to jump so height

current code

```
[self.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(0, 2200)];
```

added action to the sprite

```
 SKAction *incRight = [SKAction moveByX:1.0 y:0 duration:0.004];
    SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction repeatActionForever:incRight];
    [self runAction:moveRight];
```

Comment: Can you define "realistic"? Your issue is quite simply combining non-physics move actions with a physics impulse. You have to apply both upwards and sideways motion as an impulse or force or by updating the pyhsics body's velocity.

Comment: i have to update pyhsics sprite velocity to what? And the vertical impulse in here how much it has to be?

Comment: Impulse is affected by the body's mass/density, there's no generally applicable answer here. Experiment. And instead of the move along x axis action you would simply add an X value other than 0 to the impulse vector, respectively update the body's velocity.x every frame to a fixed value to keep it moving at a fixed rate horizontally.

Comment: currently the sprite has a mass of 4.5